# how to format an object of array to a new one

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, mapping

I'm trying to transform an object contain array to another one with javascript. Below is an example of the object field and what the formatted one should look like.
The data after formating must show me only fileds who has the "ABS"  in funcName

```
let beforeData = {
  SUMMER: [
    { funcName: '{{WORKING_ABS}}', subject: { en: "Exercice1"} },
    { funcName: '{{PULLS_BODY}}', subject: { en: "Exercice2"} },
  ],
  WINTER: [
    { funcName: '{{FULL_BODY}}', subject: { en: "Exercice3"} },
    { funcName: '{{REST_ABS}}', subject: { en: "Exercice4"} },
  ]
};
```

I need The object to be exactly like this one

```
let AfterData ={
  worklinks: [
    {
      name: 'Exercice1',
      link: '{{WORKING_ABS}}',
    },
    {
      name: 'Exercice4',
      link: '{{REST_ABS}}',
    },
  ]
},
```

I was trying to make a method like this one (Its just a draft ) , maybe somone will help to improve this method

```
   export const functTransform = (dataaas) => {  Object.keys(dataaas).map(fiels => ({
     worklinks =>funcName.search("ABS") > -1).map(({funcName, subject}) => ({
        link: funcName,
        name: subject.en
      }))};
```

I'm new working with javascript so any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider following code:

```js
const beforeData = {
  SUMMER: [
    { funcName: '{{WORKING_ABS}}', subject: { en: "Exercice1"} },
    { funcName: '{{PULLS_BODY}}', subject: { en: "Exercice2"} },
  ],
  WINTER: [
    { funcName: '{{FULL_BODY}}', subject: { en: "Exercice3"} },
    { funcName: '{{REST_ABS}}', subject: { en: "Exercice4"} },
  ]
};

const isABS = (str) => str.indexOf('ABS') > -1;
const result = Object.values(beforeData).flat().map(o => ({link: o.funcName, name: o.subject.en})).filter(o => isABS(o.link));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this? (Reduce with forEach)

```js
let beforeData = {
  SUMMER: [
    { funcName: '{{WORKING_ABS}}', subject: { en: "Exercice1"} },
    { funcName: '{{PULLS_BODY}}', subject: { en: "Exercice2"} },
  ],
  WINTER: [
    { funcName: '{{FULL_BODY}}', subject: { en: "Exercice3"} },
    { funcName: '{{REST_ABS}}', subject: { en: "Exercice4"} },
  ]
};

function transform(inputData, funcComparator){
  if (funcComparator == undefined){
    funcComparator = (item) => item.funcName.includes("ABS");
  }  
  return Object.values(inputData).reduce((aggArr, arr) => {
    arr.forEach(item => {
      if (funcComparator(item)){
        const itemCopy = {name: item.subject.en, link: item.funcName};
        aggArr.push(itemCopy);
      }
    })
    return aggArr;
  }, []);
}

//use it to find all your "ABS":
console.log(transform(beforeData));

//another example, use it to find all your "BODY":
//console.log(transform(beforeData, (item) => item.funcName.includes("BODY")));
```

Output:

```js
[
  {
    "name": "Exercice1",
    "link": "{{WORKING_ABS}}"
  },
  {
    "name": "Exercice4",
    "link": "{{REST_ABS}}"
  }
]
```

Comment: Awesome job , how can i use it as a method to call it  `transform(beforeData)`

Comment: Great! See my updated answer, you can now pass in your initial data and a functional comparator of your choice (with a fallback of searching for "ABS").

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, please consider to up-vote and mark as accepted. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome @JamesBertaha - please consider to up-vote and mark as accepted if it solved your problem. Thank you :)